# python-docx package can not read the image file

Tags: python, python-docx

I am using python-docx package to create word documents.
When I write :

```
directory=r'folder'
document.add_picture("./folder/Bamboo Shoots.jpg")
```

Able to see an image file in the word document

Iterating through the file list directory :

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
   document.add_picture('./folder/'+filename)

I get docx.image.exceptions.UnrecognizedImageError exception
```

All images under the folders are .jpg files. Why would the same operation fail when iterating through the directory list?

Can anyone please explain the different behavior?

Comment: Are there any folders within the `./folder` folder?

Comment: Is there any chance that you have a hidden file on that dir, that's not an image? For example ```.file```. Because if this is the case may be that's the reason for the error

Comment: I checked the folder there are no hidden files and folders

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to add if statements that check whether it is a file and whether it is a JPG. That should avoid problems.

```
directory = r"folder"
filenames = os.listdir(directory)

document = Document()

for index, filename in enumerate(filenames): # loop through all the files for adding pictures
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(directory), filename)): # check whether the current object is a file or not
        if filename[len(filename)-3: len(filename)].upper() == 'JPG': # check whether the current object is a JPG file
            
            #Add images
            document.add_picture(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(directory), filename))
```

Comment: Thanks, getting the same exceptions with the above code

Comment: That is strange as this works well for me using many JPG files in a directory. Maybe you have a corrupted file?

Comment: Looked like the file image headers were corrupted. I used the pillow package to read and save the file in the same format. This process foxed the image headers and I am able to write images to a word file.